# Error while installing check style plugin for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, checkstyle, sevntu-checkstyle

I am getting the following error while installing the checkstyle plugin for my eclipuse via the update manager

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>     Software being installed: EclipseCS SevNTU plugin feature 1.5.0 (com.github.sevntu.checkstyle.checks.feature.feature.group 1.5.0)
>     Missing requirement: Sevntu eclipse-cs Extension Plugin 1.5.0 (com.github.sevntu.checkstyle.checks 1.5.0) requires 'bundle net.sf.eclipsecs.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: EclipseCS SevNTU plugin feature 1.5.0 (com.github.sevntu.checkstyle.checks.feature.feature.group 1.5.0)
>       To: com.github.sevntu.checkstyle.checks [1.5.0]

I am using the below update site.

> http://eclipse-cs.sf.net/update/

I have googled a lot on this but could not find a appropriate solution.
Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you attempt to install is `Contact all update sites during install to find required software` checked ? If not, it should be :

[image]

**Expected Result**

When using the update site in OP's post, following is the expected result :
[image]

#### Offline Installation

From **[this](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/downloads.html)** page :

> Alternatively the Checkstyle Eclipse Plug-in can be downloaded from
>   the Eclipse Checkstyle Plug-in's SourceForge download site. 
>   The download consists of a archived update site (file name
>   net.sf.eclipsecs-x.x.x.buildstamp-updatesite.zip), containing all
>   mandatory and optional parts of the plugin.
>
> The plugin can be installed from the archived update site in the following ways:
>
> ```
> 1. Via Eclipse's P2 Installation Manager similar as described above, pointing to the archive file instead
> 2. Extracted into Eclipse's dropins folder.
> ```

So, the steps are as follows :

1. Download the file referred above from **[here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-cs/files/Eclipse%20Checkstyle%20Plug-in/5.5.0/)**
2. Add the downloaded file as an 'Archived Download site' like so :

[image]

3. After that you should get the following :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ashutosh. I have checked that check box. Also one thing I observed is, when the eclipse contacts the update site and lists all the available softwares on the site, i could not see the check style plug in details. it is showing only the EclipseCS SevenNTU plug in details.  No Luck :(

Comment: I have just posted a snapshot of what I get. You mean to say you don't get the `Checkstyle` section at all ? Which version of Eclipse are you using ?

Comment: If you can't get the repository to appear try the offline installation according to the new `Offline Installation` section I'll be adding in momentarily

Comment: Thanks Ashuthosh. This has helped me. Let me tell where I have done the mistake. I tried both offline installation and copying to dropins folder but I didnt succeed. This is because, i copied the plugin folder from my friends machine instead of downloading it from the web. I compared both the folders and they are different. So anyways thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 1):

I think Ashutosh' answer should have worked, alternatively another option is to download the zip archive from 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-cs/files/Eclipse%20Checkstyle%20Plug-in/5.5.0/
and extract it to eclipse plugins folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think the caveat here is the plugin's homepage http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/ gives http://sevntu-checkstyle.github.com/sevntu.checkstyle/update-site/ as the installation URL, but it does not work (Yes?). However on http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/downloads.html a different installation URL http://eclipse-cs.sf.net/update/ is given, which turns out to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

### **Eclipse Mars (4.5.1)**

#### Installation

You can install Checkstyle plugin from the **Marketplace**.

1. **Help > Eclipse Martketplace...**

   [image: Eclipse Marketplace]
2. Type `"checkstyle plug-in"` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   You can also type only `checkstyle` and then select the plugin from the list.

   Click on **Install**.

   [image: install]

#### Usage

1. **Window > Show View > Other...**

   [image: Show view]
2. Type `checkstyle` > select the views (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click) > **OK**

   [image: checkstyle views]
3. Right click on your project > **Checkstyle > Check Code with Checkstyle**

   [image: check code]

   The output will be shown in the checkstyle views (2 tabs).

   If you listed all the violations for a type (using the arrow / right click / double click), you can go back using the "Go back to the master view" arrow:

   [image: go back arrow]

Comment: Any news for this on eclipse 2018-12? I can't find the plug-in at the market place. Neither can I drag and drop the installer link into my eclipse instance nor can I find it in the update sites.

Comment: @Torsten I didn't use it recently. I can't help you with an updated information.

Comment: It must've been an issue with 2018-12. I can install it with 2019-03.