# Checkstyle is not working while building the project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle, sevntu-checkstyle

I am facing checkstyles issue while building the project. Please guide me based on my below error message as soon as possible.

Errors occurred during the build:

> Errors running builder 'Checkstyle Builder' on project 'CMS'.
>
> cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate   ReturnNullInsteadOfBoolean
>          cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate ReturnNullInsteadOfBoolean
>          cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate ReturnNullInsteadOfBoolean
>          cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate ReturnNullInsteadOfBoolean

Answer (score 1):

`ReturnNullInsteadOfBoolean` is not part of the core Checkstyle distribution.  Instead, it is part of [SevNTU](https://github.com/sevntu-checkstyle/sevntu.checkstyle) - which is typically not installed into Eclipse by default.

In Eclipse, under the "Help" menu, select "Install New Software...".  Search for "EclipseCS SevNTU plugin feature", check its box, then install.

This may also appear as "Extension for eclipse-cs plugin with additional Checks".

See also: [Error while installing check style plugin for eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865025/error-while-installing-check-style-plugin-for-eclipse)

Please comment back if this still doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for quick response but, I am unable to fix according to above suggestion. I followed  now it is is having "EclipseCS SevNTU " as well but it is throwing exception

Comment: Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Checkstyle Builder' on project 'cms-ws'.
cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate RedundantThrows
cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate RedundantThrows
cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate RedundantThrows
cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate RedundantThrows

Comment: RedundantThrows was removed with version 6.2 of Checkstyle, and will need to be removed from your project's Checkstyle configuration.  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919444/java-checkstyle-redundant-throws

Comment: @user2424101 - Please see above.